# Swift 2 - UIScrollView print out zoomScale

Tags: uiscrollview, swift2, zooming

In my app I use a `UIScrollView` with the option to zoom it.

My code works but what I am trying to achieve now is to get the current zooming value while zooming the view.

Using the code below I get my app to crash with error: `(llbd)'. Is there a way I can achieve this?

```
func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {

    let currentScale = scrollView.zoomScale // error: (llbd)

    print(currentScale)

    if currentScale == 1.0 {
        print("zoom scale is = 1")
    }else if currentScale > 1 {
        print("zoom scale is > 1")
    }

    return scrollView.viewWithTag(VIEW_FOR_ZOOM_TAG)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved using:

```
func scrollViewDidEndZooming(scrollView: UIScrollView, withView view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {

        print(scale)

    }
```